# Can't read data using read_csv due to encoding errors

Tags: python, pandas, csv, encoding, vaex

So, I am facing a huge issue. I am trying to read a csv file which has '|' as delimiters. If I use `utf-8` or `utf-sig-8` as encoders then I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

but I use the `unicode_escape` encoding then I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode byte 0x5c in position 13: \ at end of string
```

Is it an issue with the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

it worked after I 'Saved with Encoding - utf-8' in Sublime Text Editor. I think the data had some issues.